# How to limit drop down list FindByText to first result

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using this code to find an item by text:

```
ddlCountry.Items.FindByText("someCountry").Selected = true;
```

I receive an exception that says the drop down list cant multiselect which sounds reasonable to me. I'm not sure how to refactor the code above to tell it to select only the first item it finds.

Note: It's a group drop down list with quick picks which is why there is duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `FindByText` only returns one `ListItem`, you could try clearing the selection and then your Selected assignment should work:

```
ddlCountry.ClearSelection();
ddlCountry.Items.FindByText("someCountry").Selected = true;
```

Comment: perfect. I thought it was an error based on multiple results found.

Answer (score 0):

Use value instead:

```
dl.Items.FindByValue("value").Selected
```

Each country should have unique value

Comment: That won't work, as I stated above it is a group drop down list which contains some duplicate countries, the values for the list are the pk for the countries table.